# Reading a JSON object value when key contains "." in Jmeter JSON Extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm trying to read a value of a JSON object where a key have a "." in the middle. The object looks like this,

```
{
  "urls" :
   {
     "url.pdf":"test Link"
   }
}
```

I tried to read the value with **urls.url.pdf**, But I think since there is a "." value inside the key, it's trying to find a "pdf" inside "url".
Can anyone suggest a way to extract the "test Link" value in the JSON Extractor of Jmeter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [surround your attribute name containing dot with quotation marks](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) like:

```
`$.urls.['url.pdf']`
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Escape dot with `\`

```
 $.urls.url\.pdf
```

Comment: I tried this one, still jmeter it says NOMATCH. Anyway it seems like the only way to escape the character. Will give it a try again.

Comment: @MudithaPerera  Try `$['urls']['url.pdf']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below for your JSON with your appropriate Match No.

```
$..urls.*
```

This will fetch your required url.pdf

**JSON Extractor**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

---

In case the JSON starts to expand with more children and complexity, you can extend the expression with additional .*

Example JSON:

```
{
"urls": [{
        "url.pdf": "test Link 1",
        "name": "Kelly Rosa"
    },
    {
        "url.pdf": "test Link 2",
        "name": "Guadalupe Guy"
    },
    {
        "url.pdf": "test Link 3",
        "name": "Berg Bowers"
    }
]}
```

In such a case, you can use as below and extract the necessary Match No. depending on your requirements

```
$..urls.*.*
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it too. Then I moved to a regex extractor. Dimitri has posted the correct way bellow. That you for the suggestion.